# VueJS2/Vuex Computed property not behaving as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a datastore with a submodule, both having one variable:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        foo: true,
    },
    modules: {
        secondmodule: {
            namespaced: true,
            state: {
                bar: 0,
            },
            mutations: {
                updateBar: (state, value) => {
                    state.bar = value;
                }
           }
        }
    }
})
```

In my app, I want to display a snackbar for 2 seconds when the value of `foo` changes to true:

```
<template>
    <v-app id="example-1">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'secondpage'}">Link</router-link>
        {{data.connected}}
        {{this.$dataStore.state.foo}}
        <main>
            <v-fade-transition mode="out-in">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </v-fade-transition>
        </main>
        <v-snackbar success top :timeout="2000" v-model="data.connected">
            connection established!
        </v-snackbar>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        computed:{
            data() {
                return {
                    connected: this.$dataStore.state.foo,
                    bar: this.$dataStore.state.secondmodule.bar
                }
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

Since `foo` is initialized with true, the snackbar is shown on startup-

Strangely, when I click the link to secondpage, which mutates the `bar` variable:

```
created() {
   this.$dataStore.commit('secondmodule/updateBar', 1)
}
```

the snackbar shows up again and I observed that `connected` quickly changed to false and true again after clicking the link. The value `foo` is always true and has never changed, so how come the computed property `connected` changes?

Edit: Since I failed to provide a working fiddle, I added the code here, if anyone would like to take a look at it

https://github.com/netik25/vueProblem

Comment: Why are you setting this up as a plugin? Why not just pass the store object to the root Vue instance and reference it via `this.$store`?

Comment: Hmm since I need to access the store from everywhere, I thought I should make it available globally by registering it as a plugin. But sure if there is a better way I am looking into it. Do you thunk it could be the reason for my issue?

Comment: If you just import `store` in the `main.js` file and pass it to the root `Vue` instance (like `new Vue({ el: '#app', store, router, render: h => h(App) });`), then you can access the store from that and any child instance via `this.$store`. That might be part of the issue.

Comment: A couple other things that might be causing unexpected behavior: 1) you're using `data.connected` as a `v-model` even though it's a computed property. 2) you've created a computed property named `data` which seems unnecessary and would make sense just as the [`data` method](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) which sets up the Vue instance's data properties.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions seemed to have solved the problem! It seems it was the fact that I used a computed property as a v-model . I now used a getter (and empty setter since I don't need 2 way databinding).I guess that's still not how it should be done in my case right? I don't undersatnd how to use this mapState function that I'm seeing in some examples. If you can post your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept that as the answer to the issue!